# Make specific socket leave the room is in

Tags: socket.io

I'm trying to unsubscribe a socket and make it leave the room he is in. I know his socket.id, to make you understand better, when the creator of the room leaves, a specific socket/all sockets should leave. Ty!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To leave a room, you use this:

```
socket.leave(roomName);
```

If you only have the `socket.id` for the socket, then you can get the socket that corresponds to that id with:

```
let socket = io.sockets.connected[id];
socket.leave(roomName);
```

If you want to clear everyone out of a particular room, you can do that like this:

```
function clearRoom(room, namespace = '/') {
    let roomObj = io.nsps[namespace].adapter.rooms[room];
    if (roomObj) {
        // now kick everyone out of this room
        Object.keys(roomObj.sockets).forEach(function(id) {
            io.sockets.connected[id].leave(room);
        })
    }
}
```

All this code runs only on the server as rooms are a server-side concept only.

Comment: Ty, gonna bookmark this answer, that's exactly what I  was looking for ;)

Comment: hey @RazvanAlex  is , in `io.sockets.connected[id].leave(room);` .leave(room) I got an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'leave' of undefined` can you tell me what happen? my socket version is 2.2.0