# how to get the socket instance from socket id in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I want to find the socket instance using the socket id

I saw a solution on stackoverflow and tried it, but it didn't work.
[Make specific socket leave the room is in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880435/make-specific-socket-leave-the-room-is-in)

```
exports.removeParticipant = ({ data }) => {
    const { roomId, toBeRemovedSocketId } = data;
    const roomFound = rooms.find((room) => room.id === roomId);
    if (roomFound) {
      const user = roomFound.connectedUsers.find(
        (user) => user.socketId === toBeRemovedSocketId
      );
      /* Removing the user from the room.connectedUserArray . */
      roomFound.connectedUsers = roomFound.connectedUsers.filter(
        (user) => user.socketId !== toBeRemovedSocketId
      );
      //i tried this but it throws error 
      let socket = io.sockets.connected[toBeRemovedSocketId];
      socket.leave(roomId);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511976/how-can-i-export-socket-io-into-other-modules-in-nodejs/68167653#68167653

Comment: @Prathamesh More thanks for your response but I'm not trying to get  the whole io object but the socket object for specific socket id

Answer (score 0):

my own research led me to a solution.

```
let socket=io.sockets.sockets.get(toBeRemovedSocketId);
socket.leave(roomId)
```